# array flip collision issue

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function/method I am unaware of that avoids removal of like keys when the array is flipped. Example below:

**Original array:**

```
Array ( [last_modified] => input [published] => input [project_content] => textarea )
```

**With array flip (collision of keys):**

```
Array ( [input] => published [textarea] => project_content )
```

Comment: How would you want to handle collision?

Comment: the end thing im trying to accomplist is to run an array search to return for example inputs. but that can only be run if i switch the values so that input is the key. but if i do that i loose all but one of my inputs.

Comment: @Alex: So you want all the keys that have the value `"input"`? In that case, `array_keys($array, "input")` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to preserve your keys, you can have a two dimensional array:

```
<?php
$arr = array ( 'last_modified' => 'input', 'published' => 'input', 'project_content' => 'textarea' );
$result = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $result)) {
        $result[$v][] = $k;
    } else {
        $result[$v] = array($k);        
    }
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

[This will print out:](http://ideone.com/7n52s2)

```
Array
(
    [input] => Array
        (
            [0] => last_modified
            [1] => published
        )

    [textarea] => Array
        (
            [0] => project_content
        )

)
```

Comment: awesome. was trying all this crazy stuff with array_keys, and array_values and computing the diffrence and what not. i was wondering if you could send me in the direction as to how to get just an array with the fieldnames, in this case, of `last_modified`, and `published`? so basically the `array_values` of the input array.

Comment: like this: `$arrayInput = array_values($result['input']);`?

Comment: `$result['input']` should suffice

Answer (score 1):

There is a dead simple way to get all the keys in the array that have the value `"input"` using the standard function `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_keys($array, "input");
```

That is all; [**see it in action**](http://ideone.com/8H3YEl).

Comment: Jon this isnt exactly what I was asking but I appreciate the effort. Upvote.